# Need help with ZTE router config.bin file decryption and encryption

Tags: tools, encryption, decryption

bin file extracted from a ZXHN H168N V3.1. RouterPassView is able to decrypt the file successfully but the tool can't re-encrypt the file, it gave me some info about the method used to decrypt here they are

File Type: 29
Encrypted Data Start Position: 227
Encryption Algorithm: AES-128
Encryption Key: 34303263333864653339626564363635
Compression: zlib/deflate

am a noob when it comes to this stuff so idk how to code my own tool does anyone know a tool that i could use to decrypt and re-encrypt the file

Comment: They use zlib encryption in the firmware, have you tried encrypting it with zlib and repack it with binwalk squashfs? Edit: would you mind sharing decrypted firmware? So, I’ll have a look into it.

Comment: @Alex811 can yoU HELP Me to decrypt my router config Model number is ZTE ZXHN H168N V2.2 .. I TRIED ALL THE WAYS ITS SIGnature is speedport 2i . i also have mdsum of tapgram_m file ... d0e615736322e6bc91fdb4e044bcdb20 .... but cannot get the key.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [zcu](https://github.com/streetster/zte-config-utility) module (written by Mark Streetster) to decrypt/encrypt your config.bin file.

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work even when i specified the key it gave me an error that i can't remember what type/version should i use

Comment: @Ammar Yasser If you want to upload a copy of your config.bin file I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'd comment but I don't have rep.
If you're still looking into it or anyone else comes across this, [zcu](https://github.com/mkst/zte-config-utility)
indeed seems to be the way to go. I've managed to use it for a router that uses the same encryption key (ZXHN H267A V1.0) and the re-encrypted file seems byte-perfect.

It's not instantly obvious (at least with this particular key), but the answer is quite simple: RouterPassView gives you the key's hex representation, whereas zcu wants it in plain text. If you [convert](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal/) the key you wrote into text you get: `402c38de39bed665`

Btw, since I saw people ask for the config.bin, before you share it, keep in mind that the file probably contains a bunch of sensitive info (passwords used by the router and potentially your phone number if it supports VoIP).

Good luck, have fun!